# ArrayList and the sort Method of Collections

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

this method is supposed to iterate on the TreeMaps keys. Then it should add the key to an ArrayList variable because I need to return it as one. One more thing I want to do is to sort the ArrayList.

```
    ArrayList<String> getVehiclenames() {
         ArrayList<String> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();
         for (String elem : vehicles.keySet()) {
             vehicleList.add(elem);
         }
    Collections.sort(vehicleList);
    return vehicleList;
}
```

I am not 100%ly sure wether thats working, but I still couldnt believe anyways that calling a collections method just sort my vehiclelist like that. I expected something like vehicleList = Collections.sort(vehicleList);.

My questions: Is this working like that? And if yes: How is that working? I tried to look it up but my knowledge is to norrow right now.

Comment: By sorting I mean alphabetically sorting.

Comment: by getting keys from the treemap, you have already got a sorted list, why do you need sort it again?

Comment: The keys from the `TreeMap` will already be sorted.  There's no need to sort them again, unless you're after a different sort order.

Comment: @David Wallace: Yes, I read that before. But I wasn't sure about how TreeMap sort it. If I have strings there, does it alphabetically sort it everytime I add an element there?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) question. it should hep you to understand.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it from this question.

Comment: I've always thought that the best answer to "does the following code work" is invariably "test it and find out."

Comment: @David Wallace: You are right! But my question was more focused on whether is make sense to do it with Collections.sort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colletoions.sort((List list) method of the collection interface sorts based on natural ordering.
The dataType of list passed in the sort method must be of type Comparable in other words, it should implement comparable interface.

In your case, you have a list of String. and String class implements the comparable interface.

So to answer your question, yes your code should work fine.

For more information, read about comparator & comparable interface  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my mothertounge. By "resetting each element" they mean resetting the elements of the ArrayList I put in sort() ?